# Word 2016 use find and replace to add period after "et al"

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2016, wildcards

I'm trying to find all instances of "et al(space)" in a document and replace them with "et al(period)(space)". In Find and Replace with wildcards, I'm typing:

Find: (et al)( )
Replace: \1.\2

Word finds the right character sequence, but replaces "et al(space)" with "et al(space)(period)(space)".

I've tried various combinations of find-and-replace wildcards, but Word keeps adding that extra space before the period.

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but the text is in a table.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: I didn't need to use wildcards for this specific case, but was having the same problem (spaces and punctuation being added in the wrong place) in other cases where I *did* need to use wildcards. **I had to turn off Track Changes for the wildcards to work.** Kind of an annoying bug, but /shrug.

Comment: What are you planning to do if `et al` **already** has a trailing period?

Comment: I'm not able to recreate the problem - my Word replaces "et al " with "et al. " with no issues. @DavidPostill if it already has a trailing period, it's not the "et al" they're trying to replace - the one with the trailing period after the space was the incorrect sequence they were running into, not the one they were starting with. Try not using wildcards.

Comment: "Find: `(et al)( )` only finds instances of "et al" with a space immediately following it, ignoring "et al(period)" completely.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Does Word really have such a truly non-standard method of find/replace? I'd be starting with Find `et al ` Replace with `et al. `

Comment: @mael' Huh. That worked! I guess I was making it more complicated than I needed to. Without using wildcards, I typed find: `et al ` (with a space after et al) and replace: `et al. ` (with a period and a space after et al). Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that worked - it did seem to be a bit "over-thunk"   ;) I'll drop it in a simple answer for posterity.

Comment: answer's up! just accept it so it can be marked as finished!

Comment: I deleted mine - don't need 2 answers saying the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use wildcards. "et al " can be replaced using "et al. " without issue:
[image]
I highlighted both entries to show the trailing spaces.